# What is benefit of ArcPy function GetParameterAsText?

Tags: arcpy, parameters

I know that the purpose of the ArcPy [`GetParameterAsText`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/getparameterastext.htm) function is to return parameters as text, but what is the benefit of doing that?

Comment: How do you find the list of parameters? (from arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0))
I've inherited scripts from a predecessor that uses this a lot, and I need to be able to edit these parameters to provide new/different options in the dropdown that the user sees. I'm new to python, arcpy. Can read most of it and understand what's being asked, but I can not figure out where the parameters come from, to be able to update them as needed.

Answer (score 7):

The summary on the Esri [`GetParameterAsText`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/getparameterastext.htm) documentation states:

> Gets the specified parameter as a text string by its index position
>   from the list of parameters.

Functionally this allows you to pass arguments to a Python [script tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/creating-tools/a-quick-tour-of-creating-script-tools.htm). Script tools allow you to provide custom functionality in a GUI to those who do not want to use Python.

The documentation also provides an example of the usage:

```
import os
import arcpy

# Set the input workspace, get the feature class name to copy
#  and the output location.
arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
in_featureclass = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
out_workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

out_featureclass = os.path.join(out_workspace,
                                os.path.basename(in_featureclass))

# Copy feature class to output location
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(in_featureclass, out_featureclass)
```

Comment: so in this example the tool dialog box would have those three parameters that are prompting the user to input? Also, is the os.path.join trying to join different workspaces?

Comment: Yes, the script tool dialogue box would have those three parameters which the user can input in the script tool. `os.path.join()` is combining the workspace path (e.g. `/path/to/your/geodatabase.gdb`) and the basename (e.g. `some_name`) to produce `/path/to/your/geodatabase.gdb/some_name`

Answer (score 4):

In the [ArcGIS Pro Help for `arcpy.GetParameterAsText()`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/getparameterastext.htm) its Summary is that it:

> Gets the specified parameter as a text string by its index position
>   from the list of parameters.

The way I think of it is that it is the means used to communicate, as text rather than objects, the choices made by an end user from the tool dialog that fronts a Python Script Tool of ArcPy.

The first parameter that the tool's author configures on its tool dialog is referenced from the script by using an index of 0 i.e. `arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)`.

There is an alternative way to reference the first parameter on the tool dialog, and that is as `sys.argv[1]` but that has limitations in the number of characters that it can accept whereas `arcpy.GetParameterAsText()` has no character limit.  The two alternatives are documented in [Accessing parameters in a script tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/accessing-parameters-in-a-script-tool.htm).